# Is there any possibility to have htaccess 301 Redirects with absolute paths?

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect, wpml

i wondering if there is any way to have redirects like

```
Redirect 301 https://www.mypage.com/test https://www.mypage.com
```

as background: i need this because i have a website with 3 different languages and each language runs on a different domain. If I'm doing /test with an relativ path it will affect each of my domains but i only want to have the redirect for one specific domain.

i was trying it as i showed in my example but it was then no longer working.
i also was trying it with RewriteCond for my apache directives but it was also not working with absolute paths

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> Redirect 301 https://www.mypage.com/test https://www.mypage.com
> ```

The mod_alias `Redirect` directive matches against the URL-path only.

You need to use mod_rewrite to check the `Host` header using the `HTTP_HOST` server variable in a *condition* (`RewriteCond` directive). For example:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =www.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^test$ https://www.example.com/ [R=302,L]
```

The `RewriteRule` *pattern* (first argument) is a regex that matches against the URL-path only (similar to the `Redirect` directive, except there is no slash prefix when used in `.htaccess`).

The above will issue 302 (temporary) redirect from `https://www.example.com/test` (HTTP or HTTPS) to `https://www.example.com/`.

If you are redirecting to the same hostname then you don't necessarily need to include the scheme+hostname in the *substitution* string (2nd argument to the `RewriteRule` directive). For example, the following is the same as above<sup>***1**</sup>:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =www.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^test$ / [R=302,L]
```

(<sup>***1**</sup> Unless you have `UseCanonicalName On` set in the server config and `ServerName` is set to something other than the requested hostname.)

Note that the above matches `www.example.com` exactly (the `=` prefix operator on the *CondPattern* makes it a lexicographic string comparison).

To match `example.com` or `www.example.com` (with an optional trailing dot, ie. FQDN) then use a regex instead. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(example\.com) [NC]
RewriteRule ^test$ https://www.%1/foo [R=302,L]
```

Where `%1` is a backreference to the first captured group in the preceding *CondPattern* (ie. `example.com`). So, the above will redirect `https://example.com` (or `www.example.com`) and redirect to `https://www.example.com/foo` (always www).

Reference:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond

Comment: thank you for this detailed comment! With the explanation I was able to solve my problem! The query for the http_host has solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

In this case you need write a RewriteCond, as follow example:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /test1
RewriteRule (.*) https://example.com/test1/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /test2
RewriteRule (.*) https://example.com/test2/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: But then i again have the relativ path /test which is then also enabled for my 2 other domains but i only need it for one of my domains

Comment: Add one more condition:
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example.com

Comment: Unfortunately, this example will result in an endless redirect-loop since the regex is missing _anchors_ and you are redirecting back to "itself" (and then appending the original URL for some reason?). eg. `/foo/test1/bar` would be redirected to `/test1/foo/test1/bar` to `/test1/test1/foo/test1/bar` etc.